# Ubuntu which command find nothing

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS 2.0 tutorial : [Using ament to build a custom package: Create an overlay](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Ament-Tutorial#create-an-overlay)
It says that we can use Ubuntu command ***which*** to see the path before and after we **source ~/ros2_overlay_ws/install/local_setup.bash**. But it just shows nothing as I typed ***which talker***. I also tried my ros working space, it shows nothing, too. No matter I source setup.bash/local_setup.bash or not. If I type ***which ls***, it works fine to show me ***/bin/ls***. Although I can still run these ros package correctly, but I'm really curious to know what's wrong in my environment setting, should I set any ros environment variable to let which command works fine?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279354/ubuntu-which-command-find-nothing/) by [Josper](https://answers.ros.org/users/30246/josper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I seem to find the reason, ***which*** command will search through **PATH**. local_setup.* and setup.* will only append **~/ros2_overlay_ws/install/bin** to **PATH**, but demo_nodes_cpp will be put into **~/ros2_overlay_ws/install/lib** folder. So they won't be found by ***which*** command.

---

Originally posted by [Josper](https://answers.ros.org/users/30246/josper/) with karma: 73 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0